# Alter summary report to sort alphabetically

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, code-snippets

I'm using *Advanced Order Export for WooCommerce* to get a summary by products.
Algo+ (dev of this plugin) show an example to alter that summary report and sort it by SKU but i would like to sort the result alphabeticaly but i just can't.

```
add_action('woe_summary_before_output' , function() {
  uasort($_SESSION['woe_summary_products'], function($a,$b) {
    if( empty($a['sku']) AND empty($b['sku']) )
        return 0;
    if( empty($a['sku']) )
        return 1;
    if( empty($b['sku']) )
        return -1;
    return strcmp($a['sku'],$b['sku']);
  });
});
```

Comment: Your code is not reproducible. Can you share a dataset where this fails?

Comment: This code doesn't failed, it just sort by SKU and i want it to sort alphabeticaly.
You can read more about context over here https://docs.algolplus.com/algol_order_export/alter-summary-report/

That plugin export data from database to .xls file with 2 columns `product_name` & `total_quantity`.

Comment: Ok, so sku is the first priority and product name is the second?

Comment: Yes this is exact !

Comment: I answered .....

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your requirement, you would just need to add product name comparisons at the bottom when the SKUs of 2 products are same. [`strcasecmp`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strcasecmp.php) seems to be the best fit for this.

```
 uasort($_SESSION['woe_summary_products'], function($a,$b) {
    if( empty($a['sku']) AND empty($b['sku']) )
        return 0;
    if( empty($a['sku']) )
        return 1;
    if( empty($b['sku']) )
        return -1;
    if( strcmp($a['sku'],$b['sku'])  == 0) return strcasecmp($a['product_name'],$b['product_name']);
    return strcmp($a['sku'],$b['sku']);
  });
```